# LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions. Layout Builder is not Working insisde CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layoutbuilder

I am using CustomScrollView() with SliverFillRemaining and Inside it I used a row with two expanded widgets side by side. I want to use LayoutBuilder inside those Expanded Widgets but it is throwing an error. What is the possible solution to it?

I want to get the dynamic size of those Expanded Widgets whenever the user changes the width or height of the screen.

Here is the code

```
Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: blackColor,
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverFillRemaining(
                  hasScrollBody: false,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: Responsive.isMediumDevice(context) ? 4 : 1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: screenWidth,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 216, 244, 241),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
                                      Responsive.isSmallDevice(context)
                                          ? 35
                                          : 0),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(
                                      Responsive.isSmallDevice(context)
                                          ? 0
                                          : 35),
                                  bottomRight: const Radius.circular(35))),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                  child: Image(
                                      width: Responsive.isSmallDevice(context)
                                          ? screenWidth * 0.35
                                          : screenWidth * 0.12,
                                      height: Responsive.isSmallDevice(context)
                                          ? screenWidth * 0.35
                                          : screenWidth * 0.12,
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                      image: const AssetImage(
                                          'assets/images/logo1.png')),
                                ),
                                FittedBox(
                                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Quranic Quotes',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.oleoScript(
                                        color: const Color(0xff23504D),
                                        fontSize: 40,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: Responsive.isMediumDevice(context) ? 5 : 1,
                        child: Container(
                          color: blackColor,
                          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, size) {
                            final parentWidth = size.maxWidth;
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 25, horizontal: screenWidth * 0.08),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: Responsive.buttonWidth(context),
                                    height: 45,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                                      // color: color4,
                                      gradient: const LinearGradient(
                                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                          colors: [
                                            // color1,

                                            color5,
                                            color4,
                                            color3,
                                            color2,
                                          ]),
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: FittedBox(
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Create Account',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 17,
                                              color: blackColor),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    width: Responsive.buttonWidth(context),
                                    height: 45,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                                      border:
                                          Border.all(color: mainMediumColor),
                                      color: blackColor,
                                    ),
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: FittedBox(
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Log In',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontSize: 17, color: whiteColor),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: screenWidth * 0.09,
                                        vertical: 15),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        const Expanded(
                                          child: Divider(
                                            color: whiteColor,
                                            thickness: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                              screenWidth * 0.005),
                                          child: const Text(
                                            'OR',
                                            style: TextStyle(color: whiteColor),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const Expanded(
                                          child: Divider(
                                            color: whiteColor,
                                            thickness: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    width: Responsive.buttonWidth(context),
                                    height: 45,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                                      // border: Border.all(color: mainMediumColor),
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                    ),
                                    child: FittedBox(
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'Google',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                                fontSize: 17,
                                                color: whiteColor),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )));
```

Here is the Error

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require running the layout callback speculatively, which
might mutate the live render object tree.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  SliverFillRemaining
  SliverFillRemaining:file
```

Comment: you are using customscrollview for a single sliver, I'm not sure why. You could maybe try single childscrollview or use slivertoboxadapter for the top box widgets

Comment: In this case, SingleChildScrollView was not working because of expanded widgets inside Row, So I tried CustomScrollView with SliverFillRemaining which worked for scrolling but not allowing LayoutBuilder inside it. I will surely try Slivertoboxadapter.